# Adding code to the shipment print action?

Tags: magento2, shipment

**Magento 2.3.3**

I am trying to add some code to the print action which is available in a created shipment. Where would I find the code for that, or is there another way of adding code?

I want to send the shipment mail to the customer when the print button is clicked from inside the shipment.

Thanks!